# No Cloud SQL instances to proxy when connecting dataproc cluster to Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a problem with the dataproc initialization action for cloud-sql-proxy installation.
I used this initialization action:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy
setting to 0 the readonly enable_cloud_sql_metastore variable.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the init action just to provide connectivity for workloads without using the Hive metastore, you should be using *only* the `additional-cloud-sql-instances` metadata key instead of `hive-metastore-instance`; you would just leav `hive-metastore-instance` blank and use:

```
--metadata "additional-cloud-sql-instances=<PROJECT_ID>:<REGION>:<ANOTHER_INSTANCE_NAME>=tcp<PORT_#>[,...]"
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now my cluster starts correctly.
But now I have another issue: my sql client can't connect to sql instance because of the user. But this user can access correctly on the instance with no proxied connection. 
I set correctly the IAM user on the proxy.